# Laravel TinyMce-file manager could not browse file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, tinymce-4, file-manager

I just start learning laravel and now I use TinyMCE as editor. I want to add File Manager into the editor. I bump into a package https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager. I also go through the docs, but I am not sure about the path_absolute. Eventually, I get a message 'Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.' when I browse file.

Could you guys help me fix this???

Comment: Would you share your code for both frontend and backend?

Comment: sorry i dont have frontend yet. and i just copy the code from docs to add this file manager.